# What does "apt-get install" do (with no arguments)

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a dockerfile that issues:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install
```

as one of the last steps before running the program. Im not sure what the install command does with no arguments. I think I understand correctly that the update is basically just pulling latest package information thats available in the repositories.